# display text and button in proper positions using css

Tags: html, css

visit [link1](http://test.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) , Its fine. But visit [link2](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) Some problems are there

1)in 2nd link, there is **huge gap** b/w Rs 25 & "Selling Price + Rs 10 Delivery", Add to cart & buy now button.

2)Also only text **"off"** is visible, "50" went inside the "check delivery availability" box. 50 & off should visible

we are using this code :

```
.wk_mp_design .sell_price {  display: none;}
.wk_mp_design .label.yousave_label {display: none;}
.wk_mp_design .old-price .price {color: #a0a0a0;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;}
.wk_mp_design .you_save_price {color: green;font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;}
.wk_mp_design .you_save_price::after {content: "OFF";}
.wk_mp_design .special-price .price {color: #000;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;}
.wk_mp_design .regular-price .price {color: #000;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;}
.wk_mp_design .special-price {border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;clear: both;}
.wk_mp_design .You_savee {float: right;position: relative;top: -49px;}
.wk_mp_design .You_savee .special-price.yousave {border: medium none;}
.wk_mp_design .desc.std {border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;}
.wk_mp_design .mrp {display: none;}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you compare the two sites? You have different markup in the second one which causes this problem.

Comment: we have different html & php code.

Comment: you should validate your HTML first in both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1> height is the issue; use this

```
.product-view .product-essential .product-shop .price-box {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 75px;
}
```

> 2> top value is the issue; use this

```
.Quick .You_savee {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 37px;
    color: green;
    left: 151px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    top: -70px !important;
    width: 49px;
}
```

> if above classes are used in multiple places just override these classes

Comment: Please don’t recommend the use of `!important`.

Comment: yes thats correct , its a hack. but it was used by user not by me

Comment: is it? i did't know about this . whats problem in !important ?

Comment: @BabyinCoding It very easily leads to unmaintainable styles as it cannot be overruled by other normal styles. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/216074) for more information.

Comment: @Poke Thanks for valuable information. it was our team member used this. i will not use from now.

Answer (score 1):

1) Caused because of

```
<p class="special-price">
```

p elements 's margin-top

```
.Quick .special-price {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

also notice the height in

```
.product-shop .price-box {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    height: 100px;
}
```

aswell.

2) I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: 2) you can see 50% off text in 1st link, you can see only "off" in 2nd link.

Comment: Sorry was gone for lunch. You're welcome. The 2nd is because of different styles applied on element. Notice the top: -100px !important; on You_savee class on working website

Answer (score 1):

This is the relevant markup for the first site:

```
<div class="Quick_1">
    <div class="product-data">
        <div class="widget widget-static-block"></div>
        <div class="price-box">
            <p class="old-price">…</p>
            <p class="special-price">…</p>
            <p class="sell_price">…</p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="You_savee">…</div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-static-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="add-to-box">…</div>
</div>
```

And this is the same part on the second site:

```
<div class="Quick_1">
    <div class="product-data">
        <div class="widget widget-static-block"></div>
        <div class="price-box">
            <p class="old-price">…</p>
            <p class="special-price">…</p>
            <div class="You_savee">…</div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget widget-static-block"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="sell_price">…</p>
    <div class="add-to-box">…</div>
</div>
```

If you look closely, the `sell_price` element is outside of the `product-data` element in the second link which causes this problem. If you move it inside, above the `You_savee` within the `price-box`, then it will render as desired.

Comment: seems you gave perfect answer, as i dont have that much skill to analyse this, i am accepting other answer. anyways thanks a lot again.